# Formtastic - Why does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, formtastic

I have tried to use this on my test

```
<%= f.input :user, :label => 'Usuario: ' , :as => :select , :collection => @users  , :include_blank => true %>
```

And didnt work....

But when  a switch to:

```
<%= f.input :user_id, :label => 'Usuario: ' , :as => :select,      :collection => Hash[@users.map{|b| [b.nickname,b.id]}] , :include_blank => true%>
```

It does work? Does anyone knows why?

I also put it all together on the code:

```
<%= f.input :user, :label => 'Usuario: ' , :as => :select , :collection => @users  , :include_blank => true %>

<%= f.input :user_id, :label => 'Usuario: ' , :as => :select,      :collection => Hash[@users.map{|b| [b.nickname,b.id]}] , :include_blank => true%>
```

But the first one didnt work (i did just to see if was somente wrong in the @user variable)..

Is something related to the model? Does anyone knows why?

Answer (score 0):

From formtastic documentation: Many inputs provide a collection of options to choose from (like `:select`, `:radio`, `:check_boxes`, `:boolean`). In many cases, Formtastic can find choices through the model associations, but if you want to use your own set of choices, the `:collection` option is what you want. You can pass in an Array of objects, an array of Strings, a Hash…

You can check the [documentation](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic)

also `collection` is expect to receive a hash or array , but when you pass `@user` you pass an instance variable of your model and that will not work.

Comment: the **@user** variable is a return of a Model.all (User.all).. this does work on another view just without using hash... Here go the code of another view `<%= f.input :pessoa, :label => 'Selecione o cliente/pessoa',  :as => :select, :collection => Pessoa.all %>`

Comment: in simple form you can just type it `<%= f.association :pessoa , as: :select, label: 'Selecione o cliente/pessoa' %>`